# compile gdb source rpm with symbols using rpmbuild

Tags: gdb, rpmbuild

I want to make gdb rpm from gdb.spec file using rpmbuld which I can do without any problem but now in addition to that i want GDB to be complied with symbols so that when gdb is being attached to itself I should know the exact call flow and where exactly its failing.
Reason for doing this exercise is I am creating the application which will internally invoke gdb by calling gdb_init and going down failing with segmentation fault in gdb source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to prevent stripping debug symbols
in rpm build is to add exit 0 at the end of %install.

The symbols are stripped by commands that are appended
to the %install scriptlet. Adding "exit 0" prevents the
commands from being run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would to this with rpmbuild, but building gdb is really easy. Just get official source package, unpack it, then configure this way:

```
CFLAGS="-g3 -O0" path/to/gdb/source/configure --prefix path/to/your/installation/directory
make
make install
```

O0 is not strictly necessary, but if you want to debug a gdb crash, it will help.